# Ubiquiti Access Point having seriously bad WIFI Performance

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

we where searching for a way to get internet access into our guesthouse for a while now. The guesthouse is approximately 20 meters (bee line) distance from the main house. A separate internet connection would be no use, since we dont have guests there so often.

Also a cable could not be used since it would cross the complete inner courtyard, so we would have to lay it underground and this would mean structural modifications to our yard and both houses which is way to extreme.

Since the distance is only 20 meters and there are no structures between the two houses except a few trees (most of the part the guesthouse is however visible from the main house) I thaught this could easily be handeled by using a directional WIFI solultion.

I chose the Ubiquiti AG-HP-5G23 antenna and configured it as access point. The documentation said its used for connections up to 15km away and would operate between 2 and 5 GHz.

However the wifi connection is very very bad. The connection only reaches abou 16m. Right in front of the gues house you still have some coverage, but as soon as you are inside, its completely lost. So 20meters and one wall totally kill the connections.

For a device which is menat to reach up to 15km this is completely incomprehensible to me.

In comparison: our main house already has wifi coverage, we use an 5 year old fritzbox. The wifi provided by this device also reaches up to right in front of our guest house, so the coverage right in front of our guesthouse is pretty much equal from both devices. However the old fritzbox is on the other side of our main house, so it has three walls to penetrate and is much lower than the Ubiquiti AG-HP-5G23. Judging by this, the Ubiquiti directional wifi ist doing SIGNIFICANTLY worse than the 5 year old Fritzbox.

Does anyone have any experience using ubiquiti devices? Because this level of "underperformance" seems like the device either has some kind of serious fault, or I have dont something completely wrong while setting it up.

Comment: I think the kit is designed for quite narrow direction with the plate. IMO a better quality WiFi repeater would have done the job...

Comment: So far I only had bad experiences using WIFI repeaters. Also the antenna can just be set to access point mode via firmware, so its also designed for this use case. I am shure the connection would be better with a wifi bridge and two antennas. But still the first antenna showed a significant worse performance than the old radial fritzbox which had to penetrate 3 walls but showed about the same wifi coverage as the directional antenna without any obstacles did...